# Почему перестала работать функция mysqli_fetch_assoc?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php7.2

Вчера все работало.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
$mysqli->set_charset("utf8");

$query = "SELECT * FROM `tb_users`";
$result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mysqli->query($query));
$queryAuth = '';

foreach ($result as $value) {
    $queryAuth = $value['...'];
}
```

Сейчас выводит ошибку `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` и `var_dump($result)` возвращает `NULL`, а `print_r($mysqli->query($query))` возвращает объект mysql

```
mysqli_result Object
(
    [current_field] => 0
    [field_count] => 12
    [lengths] =>
    [num_rows] => 0
    [type] => 0
)
```

Почему `mysqli_fetch_assoc` возвращает `NULL`?

Comment: Наверное, потому что нет результатов по запросу в таблице? (num_rows равняется 0) (https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

Comment: @DanielProtopopov мда, кто-то из сотрудников хорошенько поработал над БД, сделал проверку перед выполнением `mysqli_fetch_assoc` на `mysqli_result` спасибо!